# How to select a range of items from Realm Database

Tags: xamarin, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have a realm database used in my xamarin android and iOS application. I have an API which feeds data to my app in a paginated manner. Whenever returns data the same is added to the DB from a ViewModel, which is common for both Android and iOS. Afterward, a broadcast is sent to update the screen. On receiving the broadcast I am trying to fetch the new set of data from the database. Let's say initially I don't have any data and on receiving the first broadcast I will fetch all the items, say 10 items, on receiving the next broadcast how can I fetch all the items except the first 10 items, and so on. ie selecting data from table in such a way that in each query the start index or row number changes.

Comment: Two ways: Realm does not (yet?) support the Linq' `Take` method, so in order to limit a query, you have to create a (some type) of `Select|Where` low/high query. I do this based upon an auto-incrementing stable id that is part of the persisted model. (Since Realm is lazy fetched, this works out to be the most performant way, but does require that your model already contains a stable id, or that you can add one). The other way is to use the fact that Realm queries are live and bind them to your UI as such and that newly added objects cause a notification thus the UI is updated.

Comment: I use both of these methods depending upon the current need and have the Realm query feed a IObservable (system.reactive). These thus pagination is "easy" in terms of each iterative subscription (or ReactiveUI/ReactiveCommand) is feed a new IObservable that contains a "new page"  of objects.